# How do I get all the labels to align on the left?

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

How do I get all the labels to align on the left, instead of being pushed out to the right for no apparent reason?

I'm using bootstrap to fix this form with like a kazillion items on it. I get in like the first 10 items, the form comes out fine (labels to the left of the input text box) then I get to "Entry Indicator" and the form just decides (on its own) to break all the labels to the right.

HTML code is below:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" id="cc_Sale" style="display:none" >
<div class="panel-heading">
<h1 class="panel-title"><a name="CC_SALE"></a>Submit a Credit Card Sale</h1>
 </div>


<form  method="POST" name="form1" action="http://localhost:10367" data-ng- submit="submit()" data-ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
    <table border="0" width="100%" id="table1">
    <input type="hidden" name="NGT_X_REQUEST_TYPE" value="CC_SALE">

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Terminal ID</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Terminal ID" name="NGT_TERMINAL_ID" size="100"  value="98765432100524">
        </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Version</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input width="628" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Version" name="NGT_VERSION" size="100" value="5FP">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Client Key</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Client Key" name="NGT_CLIENT_KEY" size="100" value="5251EC75B2184448A6AC511C2AAF122D">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Draft Capture Type</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Draft Capture Type" name="NGT_DRAFT_CAPTURE_TYPE" size="100" value="H">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >More Data Indicator</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="More Data Indicator" name="NGT_MORE_DATA_IND" size="100" value="0">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Override Function Indicator</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Override Function Indicator" name="NGT_OVERRIDE_FUNCTION_IND" size="100" value="N">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Tax Indicator</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tax Indicator" name="NGT_TAX_INDICATOR" size="100" value="0">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Entry Indicator</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Entry Indicator" class="form-control" placeholder="Entry Indicator" name="NGT_ENTRY_INDICATOR" size="100" value="0">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Payment Type</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Payment Type"  name="NGT_PAYMENT_TYPE" size="100" value="0">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Commercial Card Indicator</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Commercial Card Indicator" name="NGT_COMMERCIAL_CARD_INDICATOR" size="100" value="0">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Track Data</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Track Data" name="NGT_TRACKDATA" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628"  class="col-xs-2 control-label">Additional Entry Indicator </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Additional Entry Indicator" name="NGT_ADDL_ENTRY_IND" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Sequence Number </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Sequence Number" name="NGT_SEQUENCE" size="100" value="0001">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Account Number(Ignored if Track Data field is present)</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Account Number Ignored if Track Data field is present)" name="NGT_ACCOUNTNUMBER" size="100">
    </div>

        <label maxlength="40" width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" class="text-align:right">Expiry Date(Ignored if Track Data field is present) </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Expiry Date(Ignored if Track Data field is present)" name="NGT_EXPRDATE" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Amount </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount" name="NGT_AMOUNT" size="100">
    </div>


        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Zip Code</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip Code" name="NGT_ZIP_CODE" size="100">
    </div>


        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Address </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" name="NGT_ADDRESS" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Presence Indicator </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Presence Indicator" name="NGT_PRESENCE_INDICATOR" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >CVV2 Value </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="CVV2 Value" name="NGT_CVV2_VALUE" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" > Shift ID </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Shift ID" name="NGT_SHIFT_ID" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Clerk ID</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Clerk ID " name="NGT_CLERK_ID" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Tab Number </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tab Number" name="NGT_TAB_NUMBER" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Tip Amount</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_TIP_AMOUNT" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Ship To FullName</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_SHIPTO_FULLNAME" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Ship To Street1</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_SHIPTO_STREET1" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Ship To Street2</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_SHIPTO_STREET2" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Ship To City</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_SHIPTO_CITY" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Ship To County</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_SHIPTO_COUNTY" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Ship To State</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_SHIPTO_STATE" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Ship To Zip</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_SHIPTO_ZIP" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Ship To Country</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_SHIPTO_COUNTRY" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Ship To Phone</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_SHIPTO_PHONE" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Ship To Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_SHIPTO_EMAIL" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Bill To FullName</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_BILLTO_FULLNAME" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Bill To Street1</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_BILLTO_STREET1" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Bill To Street2</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_BILLTO_STREET2" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Bill To City</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_BILLTO_CITY" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Bill To County</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_BILLTO_COUNTY" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Bill To State</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_BILLTO_STATE" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Bill To Zip</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_BILLTO_ZIP" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Bill To Country</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_BILLTO_COUNTRY" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Bill To Phone</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_BILLTO_PHONE" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Bill To Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_BILLTO_EMAIL" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >ECommerce AAV</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_AAV" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >ECommerce XID</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_XID" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Tax Amount</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_TAX_AMOUNT" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Freight Amount</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_FREIGHT_AMOUNT" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Surcharge Type</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_SURCHARGE_TYPE" size="100">
        </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Surcharge Amount</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_SURCHARGE_AMOUNT" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Purchase Order Number</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Tax Exemption ID</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_TAX_EXEMPTION_ID" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Tax Reference Number</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_TAX_REFERENCE_NUMBER" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Customer Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_CUSTOMER_NAME" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Merchant Code</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_MERCHANT_CODE" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item SKU 1</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_SKU1" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Amount 1</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_AMOUNT1" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Description 1</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_DESCRIPTION1" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Quantity 1</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_QUANTITY1" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item SKU 2</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_SKU2" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Amount 2</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_AMOUNT2" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Description 2</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_DESCRIPTION2" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Quantity 2</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_QUANTITY2" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item SKU 3</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_SKU3" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Amount 3</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_AMOUNT3" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Description 3</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_DESCRIPTION3" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Quantity 3</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_QUANTITY3" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item SKU 4</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_SKU4" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Amount 4</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_AMOUNT4" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Description 4</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_DESCRIPTION4" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Quantity 4</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_QUANTITY4" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item SKU 5</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_SKU5" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Amount 5</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_AMOUNT5" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Description 5</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_DESCRIPTION5" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Quantity 5</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_QUANTITY5" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item SKU 6</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_SKU6" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Amount 6</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_AMOUNT6" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Description 6</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_DESCRIPTION6" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Quantity 6</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_QUANTITY6" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item SKU 7</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_SKU7" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Amount 7</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_AMOUNT7" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Description 7</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_DESCRIPTION7" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Quantity 7</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_QUANTITY7" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item SKU 8</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_SKU8" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Amount 8</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_AMOUNT8" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Description 8</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_DESCRIPTION8" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Quantity 8</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_QUANTITY8" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item SKU 9</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_SKU9" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Amount 9</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_AMOUNT9" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Description 9</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_DESCRIPTION9" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Quantity 9</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_QUANTITY9" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item SKU 10</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_SKU10" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Amount 10</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_AMOUNT10" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Description 10</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_DESCRIPTION10" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Line Item Quantity 10</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_LINEITEM_QUANTITY10" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Tax Exempt</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_TAX_EXEMPT" size="100" value="0">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >EMV Data</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_EMV_DATA" size="100" value="">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Digital Wallet Type Indicator</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_DIGITAL_WALLET_TYPE_INDICATOR" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Digital Wallet ID</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_DIGITAL_WALLET_ID" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Card Acceptor Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_CARD_ACCEPTOR_NAME" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Card Acceptor Phone</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_CARD_ACCEPTOR_PHONE" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Card Acceptor Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_CARD_ACCEPTOR_EMAIL" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Card Acceptor URL</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_CARD_ACCEPTOR_URL" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Card Acceptor Street</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_CARD_ACCEPTOR_STREET" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Card Acceptor City</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_CARD_ACCEPTOR_CITY" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Card Acceptor State</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_CARD_ACCEPTOR_STATE" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Card Acceptor Zip</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_CARD_ACCEPTOR_ZIP" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Card Acceptor Country Code (US-840)</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_CARD_ACCEPTOR_COUNTRY_CODE" size="100">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Echo created packet back <i>(Useful for debugging 
        purposes)</i>:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_X_SEND_REQUESTPACKET_AS_RESPONSE" size="100" value="0">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >URL Encoded Request <i>(Useful for debugging purposes, Allows you to enter Non ASCII data in this form)</i></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_X_URLENCODED_REQUEST" size="100" value="1">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >URL Encode Response <i>(Useful for debugging 
        purposes)</i></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_X_URLENCODE_RESPONSE" size="100" value="1">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Force Download <i>(Useful for debugging 
        purposes)</i></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="NGT_X_FORCE_DOWNLOAD" size="100" value="0">
    </div>

        <label width="628" class="col-xs-2 control-label" >Raw Response <i>  (Useful for debugging 
        purposes)</i></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=""    name="NGT_X_RAW_RESPONSE" size="100" value="0">
    </div>

    </table>
    <p>&nbsp; </p>
    <input type="button" class="panel panel-heading panel-title panel-primary"  value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" class="btn btn-default" name="SubmitBtn" onclick="HandlePostBack(this.form)"><input type="reset" class="panel panel-heading panel-title panel-primary"  class="btn btn-default"        value="Reset" name="ResetBtn"></p>


</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the helper class `.pull-left` See more at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes